# stringbuilder.tostring() assigned to datatable.select() not always working, any ideas why?

Tags: c#, datatable, stringbuilder

```
DataRow[] dr = dataTable.select(stringbuilder.ToString());
```

This is what the code that selects looks like. If the parameter is of string type, it's all fine.But if it happens to be like above, it doesn't seem to work all the time. It was all fine until yesterday and the code is broken today.

Any ideas what could cause this? We went for the stringbuilder since we were constructing the select statement by concatenating strings

The construction of the select statements happen through a switch, an example where we compare equality (we're applying filters) is as below:

```
select.AppendLine(filter.Column); 
select.AppendLine(" "); 
select.AppendLine(ComparisonOperatorsEnum.Equal); 
select.AppendLine(" '"); 
select.AppendLine(filter.Value.ToString()); 
select.AppendLine("' ");
```

Comment: Can you post the value that you use as the parameter now? Could you put here what StringBuilder.ToString() returns?

Comment: What does `doesn't seem to work` mean?

Comment: Code doesn't have day to day moods. If it's not working today, and it was yesterday, something changed.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Doesn't work. Doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Those newlines after and before the single quotes are really suspicious

Comment: The newline (\r\n) between the quotes of the value seems wrong.  Can u show the code that places the text into the string builder.

Comment: @RichardSchneider:
                    
select.AppendLine(filter.Column);
                    select.AppendLine(" ");
                    select.AppendLine(ComparisonOperatorsEnum.Equal);
                    select.AppendLine(" '");
                    select.AppendLine(filter.Value.ToString());
                    select.AppendLine("' ");

Comment: What is the value of `filter.Value` that is misbehaving (Does the value maybe contain a quote)? What is the datatype of `filter.Column` (Maybe something other than "string")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing `AppendLine` to `Append`.  Also you open yourself up to a SQL injection attack.  I suggest

```
select.Append(Filter.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use AppendLine here, you could use AppendFormat to build your Select filter

```
select.AppendFormat("{0} {1} '{2}'", filter.Column,
                                    ComparisonOperatorsEnum.Equal, 
                                    filter.Value.ToString());
```

Using `AppendLine` an automatic carriage return/line feed is added at the end of the string appended. So your filter value contains two carriage returns and new lines that aren't probably in the strings that you are searching for. Thus the match fails and nothing returns.

Using `AppendFormat` you have more control on the format of your select filter, albeit it is probably slower than a series of Append. However this lesser performance should be evaluated against the better clarity of the code.

Answer (score -1):

When you have single quotes in the stringBuilder you should use 
" **\'** "
So modify the generation of stringBuilder, so that the value will result to "COMPLETION_NAME\r\n \r\n=\r\n \'\r\nW890-CSG\r\n\' \r\n"

Comment: not true single quote inside of double quoted string is legal.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: the string is not double quoted, it's single quoted. (although it has nothing to do with string builders, so the example is not the best)